# Ruby: translating sqlite commands to postgres commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I am deploying to Heroku, and I need to translate some Ruby sample code from SQLite to Postgres.

This is the original SQLite code:

```
#SQLite table
DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://gcm-test.db')
DB.create_table? :Device do
  primary_key :reg_id
  String :user_id
  String :reg_token
  String :os, :default => 'android'
end
Device = DB[:Device]  # create the dataset
```

I have translated the table creation part, but I don't know what the last line means.

```
Device = DB[:Device]  # create the dataset
```

This is what the translated postgres code looks like so far:

```
DB = PG.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
DB.exec "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Device"
DB.exec "CREATE TABLE Device(reg_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_id text, reg_token text, os text DEFAULT 'android')"
Device = DB[:Device]  # create the dataset
```

When I try to run it locally on Heroku, I get this error:

```
in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for #<PG::Connection:0x007fe7ca7a6610> (NoMethodError)
```

Does anyone know what to do with this line?

Comment: Ruby Sequel should just do this for you.  Is there a reason you're not just using Ruby Sequel with Postgres vs. SQLite?  You can use "Sequel.connect" with a variety of SQL back-ends, not just SQLite.  e.g. `DB = Sequel.connect("postgres://localhost/mydb")`

Comment: ok thanks.  I think the PG database is being created ok.  It's just this line giving the error: Device = DB[:Device]  # create the dataset

Comment: The point is, the Sequel library does a bunch of additional work other than just some basic SQL.  The dataset handling is pretty expansive and dynamic.  You are basically replacing the Sequel ORM library and all it does (and it does a LOT) with the native Postgres client lib.  You'd have to re-implement all  the dataset handling in Ruby Sequel with your own code.

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing the one line with `DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])` ?

Comment: cool, I tried that, and it is running now!  Thanks a lot!  It seems to be creating the database ok now.  I had confused the sequel gem with sqlite before so I thought I needed to comment it out.  Anyway, thanks!!

Comment: I'm getting an error like this now:  config/puma.rb:14:in `block in _load_from': uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Puma::DSL:0x007f5b8d8e4758>>::ActiveRecord (NameError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:271:in `block in run_hooks'

Comment: do you know why this might happen?  It might have to do with sinatra   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:51:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:946:in `run!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had to change it to

```
DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL']),
```

as Joe said.